# Independent Discrete Random Variable

Tags: probability

Given 3 events $A$, $B$ and $C$ of a specific sample space, events $A, B, C$ are mutually independent if

i) $P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A)\cdot P(B)\cdot P(C)$

ii) $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$

iii) $P(A\cap C) = P(A)\cdot P(C)$

iv) $P(B\cap C) = P(B)\cdot P(C)$

For the case of discrete random variables $X,Y,Z$, they are mutually independent if

$P_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = P_{X}(x)\cdot P_{Y}(y)\cdot P_{Z}(z)$ for all $ x,y,z$

Why is it that we only have to check i) for 3 discrete r.v instead of all i), ii), iii), iv) ?

Or to put it in other way, can someone show me the proof that checking i) holds is equivalent to checking i)-iv) holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $P_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = P_{X}(x)\cdot P_{Y}(y)\cdot P_{Z}(z)$ for all $ x,y,z$
>
> Why is it that we only have to check i) for 3 discrete r.v instead of all i), ii), iii), iv) ?

If it is true for all $x$ in $X(\Omega)$ (aka the support for $P_X$), then by the Law of Total Probability, for all $y,z$ we can show that it infers:

$\mathsf P_{Y,Z}(y,z) {= \sum_{x\in X(\Omega)} \mathsf P_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) \\ = \sum_{x\in X(\Omega)} \mathsf P_X(x)\cdot \mathsf P_Y(y)\cdot \mathsf P_Z(z) \\ = \mathsf P_Y(y)\cdot \mathsf P_Z(z) }$

And so forth for the other combinations by symmetry.  There is also an analogous proof for continuous random variables.  Thus for *random variables* joint independence guarantees pairwise independence.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks!